# Navigator for ArcGIS: search by coordinates

Tags: coordinates, search, arcgis-navigator

I just installed Navigator for ArcGIS and start testing it. I tried to search using coordinates and it was not possible. It seems to search only addresses. Search by coordinates is not an included functionality?

Comment: This site alludes that you can search by coordinates, "Search—Searches for a place-name, address, coordinate location, or feature." https://doc.arcgis.com/en/navigator/iphone/navigate/quick-reference.htm#.  Can you provide an example coordinate you are trying to search by?

Comment: I have seen the website, but it is not what happens in reality. I have tried:
52.493914, 7.873873 & 
7.873873, 52.493914 & 
N52.493914, E7.873873 &
E7.873873, N52.493914

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Navigator expects to use comma as decimal separator and space in between.

ex: 52,493914 7,873873